# Link in different database tables in db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I stuck with situation in db2 where I have 2 databases. Db1 have table1 and db2 have table2. I need solution where if something is updated in table1, table 2 should be in sync. Both table have different table structure but have common columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DB2 Niknames by using "DB2 federating".

[Detailed article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/db2luwtechsupport/entry/how_to_setup_federation_between_two_db2_luw_databases2?lang=ru)

DB#2 has a table where you going to write data from a table of DB#1

You should create a nikname in DB#1 on a table from DB#2 ( table 2).

After that,  you can create after insert/update triggers on table 1 in DB#1,
where you can insert or update all changes of table-1 by simple SQL
DML instructions Insert/Update on this nikname  as a local table.